# Need confirmation of my solution

Tags: operating-system

The following code is an attempt to solve N process critical section problem. Can you please tell me if it is right or wrong! Plez give me the little detail! Plz

```
     boolean array want[1..n] [false,…., false]
      loop forever
     non-critical section
      p1: want[i] true
      p2: for all processes j< i
      p3: if want[j]
    p4: want [i] false
    p5: while not want[j] do skip
       goto p1
       p6: for a ll processes j>i
      p7: while not want[j] do skip
     critical section
         p8: want[i] false
```

Comment: Is this algorithm supposed to be formatted in a human-readable way? Without fixing the indentation it's impossible to tell what the intended control flow is...

Comment: Also, could you describe the problem it's supposed to solve, or at least link to a description of it?